# Laravel Nova Card Options Missing Function

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-nova

I was recently given a Laravel app that uses Nova and Vue in it - all three of which I've never worked with before, so apologies in advance if I ask something that should be obvious. Inside the app there is a custom card that was already setup by the previous developer that works fine and I'm just trying to add an extra property for the Vue side to read. The structure of the card is pretty basic:

```
public $width = 'full';

    public function currentUser()
    {
        return $this->withMeta(['currentUser' => Auth()->user()->id]);
    }
    public function is_active()
    {
        return $this->withMeta(['is_active' => Auth()->user()->is_active]);
    }

    public function information()
    {
        $information_id = Information::where('user_id', Auth()->user()->id)->first()->id;
        return $this->withMeta(['information' => $information_id]);
    }

    public function component()
    {
        return 'overview';
    }
```

This card shows up on the dashboard and using the Network tab in debug tools, I can see where the JSON response that goes to Vue when the card's API component is hit. The problem is, the one property I'm trying to add (`information`) doesn't show up. The full response is:

```
{
    "label": "Dashboard",
    "cards": [
        {
            "width": "full",
            "component": "overview",
            "prefixComponent": false,
            "onlyOnDetail": false,
            "currentUser": 780,
            "is_active": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried running `npm install`, `npm dev` and `php artisan nova:publish` - all are successful, but that JSON isn't picking up the new functions I added to the card's PHP file.  For the sake of just trying, I even added these two:

```
public function testing()
{
    return 'test';
}

/**
 * Indicates that the analytics should show current visitors.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function currentVisitors()
{
    return $this->withMeta(['currentVisitors' => true]);
}
```

Despite recompiling everything, those functions also don't seem to do anything - the JSON returned stays the same. I'm positive I'm doing something very basic wrong, but for the life of me can't quite figure it out.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you running `npm run dev` inside the card's root folder? Follow the [documentation](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/customization/cards.html#compiling-assets)...

Comment: I hadn't been - I just did it at the root (which I assumed did the cards too, but obviously not since I ran into a compile error that was easily fixed), but I just tried that and the new properties for the card still don't show up :-(

Answer (score 0):

I personally did create 2 components for Laravel Nova 3.x (one of them using VueJS), and what I did was:

1. Go inside the component root folder and run `npm run prod` (or `dev` ir you are testing)
2. Then, you must have your component registered as a `composer package`, so when you load the Component's `ServiceProvider`, you should have:

```php
public function boot(): void
{
    $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/../resources/views', 'component-view-name');

    Nova::serving(function (ServingNova $event) {
        Nova::script('component-view-name', __DIR__.'/../dist/js/field.js');
    });
}
```

That `Nova::serving` is the one "attaching" or sharing your desired `*.js` compiled file.

---

I am not sure about cards. My component was just a new `field`, not a `card`, but should be exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never.

Your public functions aren't automatically registered with the Vue component if you think that is what happens. The docs are a bit misleading/confusing here with the example given. Assuming you were going off of the [card options example](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/customization/cards.html#card-options), this is only really for registering your card with … well, options.

The only thing that gets through to your Vue component is whatever `jsonSerialize()` will return when you register your card with `NovaServiceProvider`. Assuming you did it like that:

```php
protected function cards()
{
    return [
        new \Scott\CoolCard\CoolCard(),
    ];
}
```

Nothing will happen. You will only see the default properties on your card (`component`, `prefixComponent`, `onlyOnDetail`, `width` as of now).

Now register your card like this:

```php
protected function cards()
{
    return [
        (new \Scott\CoolCard\CoolCard())->currentUser(),
    ];
}
```

`currentUser` will now be available as a property!

But assuming you want all of your properties available all the time, you have several options. Either add a new method that returns all of your properties via `withMeta` or even better, simply override the card's constructor and add/return them all there:

```php
public function __construct($component = null)
{
    parent::__construct($component);

    return $this->withMeta([
        'currentUser' => Auth()->user()->id,
        'is_active' => Auth()->user()->is_active,
        // […]
    ]);
}
```

And simply register your card as usual:

```php
protected function cards()
{
    return [
        new \Scott\CoolCard\CoolCard(),
    ];
}
```

You could even add more arguments to the constructor to have more control over what is returned. But then again, this might be a case better suited to the option method example mentioned above.